# Proper way to write methods

Tags: java, methods

The book "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin says **a method should do one thing**. Now for example, I have two method initialize() and play().

> initialize() should be called just before play() is called.

play() method would be called hundreds of times in my code. I can see three approaches:

**Approach-1:**

Call initialize() before play() and this could be repeated over hundreds of times.

```
initialize();
play();

...

initialize();
play();

...
```

**Approach-2:**

Put initialize() inside play() method. But this would go against "do one thing" approach.

```
void play() {
    initialize();
    ...
}
```

**Approach-3:**

I should write another method called initializeAndPlay().

```
void initializeAndPlay() {
    initialize();
    play();
}
```

Is there any other better and cleaner way to do this?

Comment: If the client always needs to call initialize before play to use the class correctly, definitely not 1.

Comment: @AndyTurner, true. This is called temporal coupling. :)

Comment: If `initialize` is always needed to perform `play` correctly use your second way.

Comment: initialize method is always needed before calling play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If play is *usually* called after initialize, I would pick the third one because it is the clearest.

If play is impossible without initialize, pick the second one.

On the other hand, I would think about the design of the class which offers the methods. In most cases, initialization is done in a constructor.

Comment: initialize must be called before play method. And using the second one, would this be a clean way? Cause it's not doing one thing. Also it is doing a hidden job `initialize` inside.

Comment: If a process consists of several steps (initialize, play, cleanUp,...) there has to be a method doing these steps. You could also use the third way if you make play and initialize private, so that you avoid them to be called separately. But in any case, I would think about your structure and whether you should put initialize into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think this strongly depends what you initialize method does. If it initializes the current object, I would go for option number 2 and guard it:

```
void play() {
 if (!initialized) {
    initialize();
 }
 ...
}
```

If it initializes the whole system/UI, I would go with option number 3.